# How to choose U in U-substitution integration method.

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a very general question I have with integration with U-Sub, I don't have a very specific example here, but how do you choose what part of the equation to be **U**?

For example, I have realized, when I was integrating using the U-Sub method, on a quotient equation, sometimes **U** is the numerator and sometimes **U** is the denominator, sometimes, it is neither (Part in the numerator or the denominator), which is very confusing.

Sometimes U-Sub doesn't work with quotients, you will need to solve by partial fraction decomposition method, why doesn't U-Sub work in this case?

Can someone explain why?

Sorry if I don't have a specific example question in this question.

Answer (score 1):

$u$-substitution is just a fancy name for running the chain rule backward.

As a reminder, the chain rule states that $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x).$ So if you have an expression of the form $\int f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) dx,$ then the indefinite integral will just be $f(g(x))+c.$

For a concrete example, consider the integral $\int 2x\text{cos}(x^2)dx.$ Since the $2x$ term is the derivative of the $x^2$ term inside the cosine expression, it means that it showed up from applying the chain rule. So if we substitute $u = x^2,$ then $du = 2xdx,$ and the entire integral becomes $\int \text{cos}(u)du = \text{sin}(u) + c = \text{sin}(x^2) + c.$